# How to select count of different values in the corresponding column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table with 3 columns: first one is ID(not important here), second is number, and third is answer. The second and third column data is as follows:

```
number : answer
1      : yes
1      : yes
1      : no
2      : yes
2      : no
3      : yes
3      : no
3      : no
```

The output is supposed to be

```
number - total Yes - total No
1      -   2       -  1
2      -   1       -  1
3      -   1       -  2
```

i.e. the total number of yes and no for each number. Can someone guide me as to how to write this select query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  number,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = 'yes' THEN 1 END) AS total_yes,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = 'no' THEN 1 END) AS total_no
FROM test_table
GROUP BY number
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53ade/5)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sqlite then it will be as follows:

```
Select Cast(number as varchar) || ' - ' ||
Cast(Sum(case when answer = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar) || ' - ' || 
Cast(SUM(case when answer = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as varchar)

from table

Group by number
```

For MySQL it will be:

```
Select CONCAT_WS(' - ', Cast(number as char),
Cast(Sum(case when answer = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as char),
Cast(SUM(case when answer = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as char))

from table

Group by number
```